# Import Chrome passwords to Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords

Am I stupid or is there no way to import Chrome passwords to Firefox without using 3rd party software/service? I mean, it's such a silly little task. I don't want to use LastPass. I found how to export Chrome passwords to .csv file but how do I import that into Firefox?

According to this there should be an Import button, except, there isn't

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/password-manager-remember-delete-change-and-import#w_viewing-and-deleting-passwords

**EDIT -** also there's the bookmark manager in Firefox, that allows you to import data from another browser, including Chrome, including cookies, but no passwords.

Comment: To quote your link: "**Note:** The Password Manager Import feature is currently available on Windows only." - is this your problem?

Comment: @AFH yepp, I'm on linux

Comment: I am, too. I have switched from Firefox to Waterfox and Pale Moon, as I need Java support, and I used the _Password Exporter_ add-on to transfer log-in data between the different versions on both Linux and Windows (it also does the importing), but I haven't found a directly compatible Chrome extension. However, the transfer file can be in either CSV or XML format, so any Chrome method of listing passwords should be easy to manipulate into the required format.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late maybe, but on linux you can import from .csv file if you activate a certain flag from about:config called signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled. Then you can see the option to import from file.
It's explained in a footnote in the mozilla support https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-login-data-file

Answer (score 4):

For those who can take current situation with Firefox as granted, here's a solution **with** 3rd party software:

1. Close Firefox
2. Open `Google Chrome` > Settings > Passwords > Next to `Saved Passwords` there are 3 dots, press them > `Export passwords` -> Save to Desktop
3. (this step requires `python3` and `pip` to be already installed)
   Open your Terminal / Console app - > `pip install ffpass` ([ffpass source code](https://github.com/louisabraham/ffpass))
4. Change console/terminal directory to `Desktop` (or where were your exported Chrome passwords saved
5. 

For Mac OS: `ffpass import -f <YOUR_CSV> -d /Users/<YOUR USER>/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/<YOUR_PROFILE>`
For Linux: `ffpass import -f <YOUR_CSV> -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/Profiles/<YOUR_PROFILE>`
For Windows: `ffpass import -f <YOUR_CSV> -d %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<YOUR_PROFILE>`

6. Delete your `CSV` with passwords from Desktop

Comment: Thank you for nice tool! Unfortunately, at the moment it has issues with recent Firefox versions starting from version 72, which makes the tool unusable.

Comment: Try installing an older version of Firefox with disabled auto-updates, then run import tool, then updating.

Comment: For Linux the directory is something like: `~/.mozilla/firefox/632asdasdf.default-123123123` (Firefox 76.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

`ffpass` doesn't work with the new versions of Firefox. You can still install an older version, import passwords and upgrade.

However, I didn't want to do that and cheesed the system a bit by using Javascript to pretend manually entering all the passwords. I made it into a github repository

https://github.com/toramanlis/chrome2firefox

Directions are in the readme

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks!!